# Turn off recommended roads for biking in Google Maps but keep the streets with dedicated bike lanes

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Google maps api v3 lets you include bike path info
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/trafficlayer#bicycling_layer

It says "Dashed routes indicate streets or paths otherwise recommended for bicycle usage."

Do you know a way to turn off the dashed routes but maintain the dark and light green routes that represent dedicated bike routes and bike lanes?

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing you can get is defining the [Basic Map Type](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#BasicMapTypes) to `MapTypeId.TERRAIN`, which displays a physical map based on terrain information, which should look something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rtcj3kmg/).

Or.. you can take advantage of the [Image Map Type](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ImageMapTypes), use your own image as map and load the bike routes on the map.

Well.. I was thinking about styling too. But it seems like once you turn off the road, you turn off the bike lanes also. Just like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/71zcx6Lz/).
You can play around with the [stylier](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) and see if you can find a way to figure it out. Be sure to share with us if you do find a way.